# Rails: passing value: view to controller to view with Javascript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In one of my forms, I have an element called event_id which value I select from a dropdown box. Once I select event_id, I want to use Ajax to call the controller, and return panel_event_id as a ruby variable that I can use in the rest of the form. Here's what I'm doing:

In routes.rb, I have the following:

```
match 'panel_event_id', :to => "panels#event_id"
```

I have the following javascript function (not sure about the syntax):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').change(set_session_event_id);

  function set_session_event_id()
  {
    var event_id = document.getElementById("event_id");
    var event_id_value = event_id.value;
    $.post('panel_event_id', { set_event_id: event_id_value });
  }
</script>
```

What do I put in my panel_controler.rb, in the following method:

```
def panel_event_id
end
```

and how do I act on it back in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could render a json in your controller :

```
def panel_event_id
  ...
  render :json => panel_event.as_json(:only => [ :id ])
end
```

After that, you could handle the success event of the post method. See the doc here : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html and here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json.